# :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac error: error reading C:\... \.android\build-cache\167256a7a343274ac6d230f06a5526cf83b55ac4\output\jars

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Good day friends,

The error 
`:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac error: error reading C:\ .... \.android\build-cache\167256a7a343274ac6d230f06a5526cf83b55ac4\output\jars\classes.jar; error in opening zip file` and also the same but ending in `cannot read zip file`

occurs when running the application.  After that, I get all sorts of errors obviously such as `package android.support.v7.app does not exist` etc.

I have tried cleaning, rebuilding, cleaning the `.android\build-cache` etc, etc, and nothing.  I have also looked at the other answers provided here, but none of them fixed this issue.

I am running jdk1.8.0_40 as JDK

This is my top gradle:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "es.sample.android.myoffice"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        }

        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            flatDir {
                dirs 'libs'
            }
        }
        apply plugin: 'android-apt'
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.1'

        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.2'

        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
        apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thanks!

**NEW EDIT**

Apparently is only affecting to:

```
Error:(18, 30) error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist
```

Comment: try Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: did you set the Jdk directory in android studio?

Comment: I tried that already but nothing.  And the JDK dir is set ok: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40 . Still not working :(

Comment: **To the person who downvoted and didn't say why**. First, it is always good manners to say why, and second, this is not a repeated post since it remains unresolved. None of the answers provided by similar posts solve this issue. I clearly mentioned that in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going crazy and trying everything that I could, I came up with a solution.

I had go back to Android Support Library version 45.  For some strange reason, version 46 was causing all this mess for `android.support.v7.app`

So do the following:

1. Download the version [here](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r45.zip) and unzip it to a local place in your computer
2. Go to your m2repository in your SDK root folder .. /extras/android and delete it
3. Cut previously unzipped m2repository folder and paste it to previous location
4. Clean and run your app